# SAP UI5 - How to disable a row in sap.m.Table Multiselect table based on row status

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a bit a tricky problem. I want to disable the row selection is `sap.m.Table`. But the Table is available in `Panel` Content

```
<VBox items="{dataModel>/Products}">
   <Panel expandable="true" id="testPanel" expanded="false" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
      <headerToolbar>
         <Toolbar style="Clear">
            <Text text="{dataModel>productText}"></Text>
         </Toolbar>
      </headerToolbar>
      <content>
         <Table id="productsTable" items="{dataModel>productsList}" id="skillsTable" visible="true" sticky="ColumnHeaders"
            mode="MultiSelect">
            <columns>
               <Column>
                  <Text text="Product Name"/>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Text text="Product No"/>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Text text="Asset"/>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Text text="Check Duplicate"/>
               </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
               <ColumnListItem >
                  <cells>
                     <Text text="{dataModel>productName}"/>
                     <Text text="{dataModel>productNo}"/>
                     <Text text="{dataModel>asset}"/>
                     <Text text="{dataModel>checkDuplicate}"/>
                  </cells>
               </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
         </Table>
      </content>
   </Panel>
</VBox>
```

If you see the above Code, There are 3 points...
1)VBox has an array of Products
2)Inside VBox there is Panel
3)Inside Panel, in Panel Content, I have given `sap.m.Table`, It means like there might be multiple tables will get generated based on the data coming from backend.

Now my requirement is like how can I disable a row based on the boolean value in `checkDuplicate`?

Below is my controller logic, what I'm trying...

```
var tbl = self.getView().byId('productsTable');
var header = tbl.$().find('thead');
var selectAllCb = header.find('.sapMCb');
selectAllCb.remove();

tbl.getItems().forEach(function (r) {
    var obj = r.getBindingContext("dataModel").getObject();
    var oStatus = obj.checkDuplicate;
    var cb = r.$().find('.sapMCb');
    var oCb = sap.ui.getCore().byId(cb.attr('id'));
    if (oStatus == "true") {
        oCb.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        oCb.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

The problem with the above logic is, if there is only one Table, then based on the Table `id`, I can get the row data and I can disable the row. But here multiple Tables will get generated dynamically, So I can't give ID for the Table.

Can someone please help me how can I disable the row based on `checkDuplicate` boolean Value?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1. Give your table a class like "multiSelectTable" and then use jQuery to find those tables. 2. Create the table in the controller with dynamic IDs which you keep track of. In both cases you the iterate through the table array.
Or third idea I just have, is maybe using XML Composite Controls. But I'm not sure if it maybe isn't to complex for what you try to solve.

Comment: @Mainz007 thank you for your response. As you suggested, i have given class for Table and through that im trying to find 'id' of the Table through loop. But using $('.skillsTablesClass').attr('id') statement. Im not able to get ID for the table. Can you please help me how can i proceed with this logic?

Comment: I would go with the idea of Voyager. Sounds like an even better solution to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an event listener for the event [modelContextChange](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/events/modelContextChange) to your table.

> Fired when models or contexts are changed on this object (either by calling setModel/setBindingContext or due to propagation)

```
<Table id="productsTable" 
       modelContextChange=".onModelContextChange"
       items="{dataModel>productsList}"
       sticky="ColumnHeaders"
       mode="MultiSelect"
>
...
</Table>
```

The event contains the parameter "id" of the current table. This way, you can retrieve the current table by its complete id and re-use your code with a minor change.

```
onModelContextChange: function(oEvent) {
    var sId = oEvent.getParameter("id");
    var tbl = sap.ui.getCore().byId(sId);
    var header = tbl.$().find('thead');
    var selectAllCb = header.find('.sapMCb');
    selectAllCb.remove();

    tbl.getItems().forEach(function (r) {
        var obj = r.getBindingContext("dataModel").getObject();
        var oStatus = obj.checkDuplicate; 
        var cb = r.$().find('.sapMCb');
        var oCb = sap.ui.getCore().byId(cb.attr('id'));
        if (oStatus == "true") {
            oCb.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            oCb.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```